# jQiuery Multiple dragging plugion not works with jqv3

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm working on this plugin:
https://github.com/javadoug/jquery.drag-multiple

My problem is, that this don't work on jQuery v3.3.1. and the latest UI.
My problem is, that this don't work on jQuery v3.3.1. and the latest UI.

Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Drag Multiple</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 1px solid silver;
            position: relative;
            top: 60px;
            left: 60px;
        }
        .box {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #draggable1 {
            top: 0px;
        }
        #draggable2 {
            top: 60px;
        }
        #draggable3 {
            top: 120px;
        }
        #draggable4 {
            top: 180px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="drag-multiple.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*$(function () {
            $(".box").draggable({multiple: true});
        });*/



        $('.box').each(function(index) {

            var options = {
                multiple: true,

            };

            $(this).draggable(options);
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="draggable1" class="box ui-selected">
        <p>Drag 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable2" class="box">
        <p>Drag 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable3" class="box ui-selected">
        <p>Drag 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable4" class="box ui-selected">
        <p>Drag 4</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

drag-multiple.js:

```
/*jslint browser: true, indent: 4, todo: true */
/*globals jQuery */
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    var options = {

        // allow consumer to specify the selection
        items: function getSelectedItems() {
            return $(".ui-draggable.ui-selected");
        },

        // allow consumer to cancel drag multiple
        beforeStart: function beforeDragMultipleStart() {
            // make sure target is selected, otherwise deselect others
            if (!(this.is('.ui-draggable') && this.is('.ui-selected'))) {
                $(".ui-draggable").removeClass('ui-selected');
                return false;
            }
        },

        // notify consumer of drag multiple
        beforeDrag: $.noop,

        // notify consumer of drag multiple stop
        beforeStop: $.noop,

        // multiple.stack
        stack: false

    };

    function preventDraggableRevert() {
        return false;
    }

    /** given an instance return the options hash */
    function initOptions(instance) {
        return $.extend({}, options, instance.options.multiple);
    }

    function callback(handler, element, jqEvent, ui) {
        if ($.isFunction(handler)) {
            return handler.call(element, jqEvent, ui);
        }
    }

    function notifyBeforeStart(element, options, jqEvent, ui) {
        return callback(options.beforeStart, element, jqEvent, ui);
    }

    function notifyBeforeDrag(element, options, jqEvent, ui) {
        return callback(options.beforeDrag, element, jqEvent, ui);
    }

    function notifyBeforeStop(element, options, jqEvent, ui) {
        return callback(options.beforeStop, element, jqEvent, ui);
    }

    $.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "multiple", {

        /** initialize the selected elements for dragging as a group */
        start: function (ev, ui) {

            var element, instance, selected, options;

            // the draggable element under the mouse
            element = this;

            // the draggable instance
            instance = element.data('draggable') || element.data('ui-draggable') || element.data('uiDraggable');

            // initialize state
            instance.multiple = {};

            // the consumer provided option overrides
            options = instance.multiple.options = initOptions(instance);

            // the consumer provided selection
            selected = options.items();

            // notify consumer before starting
            if (false === notifyBeforeStart(element, options, ev, ui)) {
                options.dragCanceled = true;
                return false;
            }

            // cache respective origins
            selected.each(function () {
                var position = $(this).position();
                $(this).data('dragmultiple:originalPosition', $.extend({}, position));
            });

            // TODO: support the 'valid, invalid and function' values
            //  currently only supports true
            // disable draggable revert, we will handle the revert
            instance.originalRevert = options.revert = instance.options.revert;
            instance.options.revert = preventDraggableRevert;

            // stack groups of elements
            // (adapted from jQuery UI 1.12.1-pre draggable)
            if (false !== options.stack) {
                var min, group;

                group = $.makeArray($(options.stack)).sort(function(a, b) {
                    return (parseInt($(a).css("zIndex"), 10) || 0) -
                        (parseInt($(b).css("zIndex"), 10) || 0);
                });

                if (!group.length) { return; }

                min = parseInt($(group[0]).css("zIndex"), 10) || 0;
                $(group).each(function(i) {
                    $( this ).css("zIndex", min + i);
                });
                selected.each(function () {
                    $(this).css("zIndex", min + group.length);
                });
            }
        },

        // move the selected draggables
        drag: function (ev, ui) {

            var element, instance, options;

            element = this;
            instance = element.data('draggable') || element.data('ui-draggable') || element.data('uiDraggable');
            options = instance.multiple.options;

            if (options.dragCanceled) {
                return false;
            }

            notifyBeforeDrag(element, options, ev, ui);

            // check to see if consumer updated the revert option
            if (preventDraggableRevert !== instance.options.revert) {
                options.revert = instance.options.revert;
                instance.options.revert = preventDraggableRevert;
            }

            // TODO: make this as robust as draggable's positioning
            options.items().each(function () {
                var origPosition = $(this).data('dragmultiple:originalPosition');
                // NOTE: this only works on elements that are already positionable
                $(this).css({
                    top: origPosition.top + (ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top),
                    left: origPosition.left + (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left)
                });
            });

        },

        stop: function (ev, ui) {

            var element, instance, options;

            element = this;
            instance = element.data('draggable') || element.data('ui-draggable') || element.data('uiDraggable');
            options = instance.multiple.options;

            if (options.dragCanceled) {
                return false;
            }

            notifyBeforeStop(element, options, ev, ui);

            // TODO: mimic the revert logic from draggable
            if (options.revert === true) {
                options.items().each(function () {
                    var position = $(this).data('dragmultiple:originalPosition');
                    $(this).css(position);
                });
            }

            // clean up
            options.items().each(function () {
                $(this).removeData('dragmultiple:originalPosition');
            });

            // restore orignal revert setting
            instance.options.revert = instance.originalRevert;

        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I modified these lines:

```
instance = element.data('draggable') || element.data('ui-draggable');
```

to this:

```
instance = element.data('draggable') || element.data('ui-draggable') || element.data('uiDraggable');
```

Nothing happened.

Web console returns no error.

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the corrected code in the index.html

```
$(function () {
    //  $(".box").draggable({multiple: true});

  $('.box').each(function(index) {
    var options = {
    multiple: true,
  };

  $(this).draggable(options);
 });
});
```

instead of:

```
 /*$(function () {
            $(".box").draggable({multiple: true});
   });*/

 $('.box').each(function(index) {

   var options = {
   multiple: true,

  };

  $(this).draggable(options);
});
```